# Fetching a dynamic image from mysql database

Tags: laravel

I'm having error with displaying a dynamic image as a background image. 
The is a ? mark with in the source code which is causing the problem.
ex: background-image: url("photos�c54c93cbarry.jpg").
Can someone please help me solve this problem.

note: I have try the meta tags

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-32"

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"

Thanks

code:

```
li style="background-image: url({{asset($banner->bgImg)}});">
```

Comment: Could you show some code pls?

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8?

Comment: Yes i have tried UTF-8